impersonal constructions with the infinitive and dative
From РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ (1924):

Вы и въ разговорѣ услышите, и въ письмѣ прочитаете, что не въ Россіи
же теперь жить еврею, а потому какъ разъ время ѣхать «домой»

What is the precise nuance of these dative impersonal constructions? A Jew CANNOT live in Russia now? or a Jew SHOULD NOT live in Russia now? Or could it be either, with the meaning appraised from context?

You don't think he should live in Russia now

It's more like "why would a Jew choose to live in Russia now".
